# Babel 7 Upgrade and Creating an Array from a Set

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Since upgrading to Babel 7, I cannot use the spread operator to create a new array from `Set`.
For example:

```
const uniqueNums = [ ...new Set([ 0, 1, 1 ]) ];
// => Set { 0, 1 }
```

The expected result is:

```js
// => [ 0, 1 ]
```

If I do `Array.from(new Set([ 0, 1, 1 ]))` it works as expected.

It was working as expected, but I must have gone wrong somewhere in my Babel upgrade.

My previous `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 1%",
          "uglify": true
        },
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "transform-class-properties",
      {
        "spec": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Upgrade to `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    return {
      presets: [
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            modules: false,
            targets: {
              browsers: '> 5%, not dead'
            },
            forceAllTransforms: true,
            useBuiltIns: 'usage',
            corejs: 3
          }
        ],
        '@babel/preset-react'
      ],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        [
          '@babel/plugin-transform-spread',
          {
            loose: true
          }
        ]
      ]
    };
}
```

What is the expected configuration I am missing?

Environment details:
node: 10.16.2
babel: 7.5.5
yarn: 1.17.3

Comment: You've added `['@babel/plugin-transform-spread', { loose: true }]` which was not there in your original config. Was there a reason for that?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Without it, certains part of the app were breaking with `Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`. I imagine there's some improper implementations, but for right now I needed the upgrade to work with the code as-is. The  enabled loose configuration fixed it.

Comment: Do you have `@babel/polyfill` as a dependency installed?

Comment: @DanielVarela No, I moved to using `core-js/stable`

Comment: @DanielVarela Any chance you remember what the issue was here? Running into the same thing.

Comment: @brent sorry I don't,  but my .babelrc file looks like:

{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring"
  ]
}

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. @cameck, you was able to solve ?

Comment: @ridermansb Sorry, no I wasn't. I took the fast path and converted everything to use `Array.from` instead of `[ ...]`

Comment: Yep.. same as me :(